# Shall I define index (A) and index (B), or index (A, B), or both?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

In my table I have two closely related columns A and B. What possible considerations shall I made to decide whether to create:

- index(A) and index(B),
- index(A, B),
- both of the above?

How does this change if I:

1. use only queries like `where A = 5 and B = 10` (and never like `where A = 5`),
2. also use queries like `where A > 3 and A < 10 and B > 12 and B < 20`,
3. often use `order by (A, B)`,
4. often use `group by (A, B)`?

Note: I intentionally haven't provided more details about my particular case as I want a general answer that will also serve to others. I use mysql, but if you give more general answer that covers SQL in general that would be great.

Comment: note that I've read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291193/mysql-difference-between-add-indexa-add-indexb-and-add-ind) but it doesn't cover all of my question.

Comment: Use EXPLAIN as much as you can on your queries, and experiment with various index configurations. That should be quite instructive !

Answer (score 5):

Ok, when you have an index(A,B), MySQL can also use it as an index(A). Declaring AB and A has no sense. Declaring AB and B does, however

So you have these choices:

1. Index(A,B)
2. Index(A,B) and Index(B)
3. Index(A) and Index(B)

Comment: Good, thanks! But you mean 3 choices, also `Index(A,B)` alone?

Comment: If you never search on the `B` column without the `A` column, you can use `Index(A,B)` alone as well. The thing to remember is that **`Index(A,B)` cannot be used to search on B alone**. It's logical: think of a dictionary on lastname, firstname: finding all the people with firstname 'thomas' in there will be difficult.

Comment: thanks Konerak. But what about the query 2: `where A > 3 and A < 10 and B > 12 and B < 20`? Isn't it a case where separate index for B is needed?

Comment: Nope, think about it as a dictionary (or an excel table): first, find all lines for which the values in the first column are between 3 and 10. Then, for each of those values, find the lines where the values in the second column are between 12 and 20. MySQL uses the index, doesn't matter if you do `=`, `>`, `LIKE "12%"`... (it won't use the index for `LIKE "%12%"` though)

Comment: Great, thanks! So I've added the `alone(A,B)` to your answer also. And finally, what about option 3.? Is this the strongest solution that would cover everything covered by 1. and 2., including the `group/order by (A, B)`?

Comment: The strongest would be option 2. Option 3 contains the useless A since there already is an AB.

Comment: MySQL can only use one index per table!

Comment: @tombom: citation needed. Countercitation: [index merge](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html)

Comment: I'm sure I read it in High Performance MySQL (http://www.amazon.de/Performance-Optimierung-Datensicherung-Replikation-Lastverteilung/dp/3897213885), but can't proof that immediately. A quick google reveals following three examples: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7234/indexes-foreign-keys-and-optimization http://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/74721-multi-column-index http://www.martynov.org/2007/08/4-silly-mistakes-in-use-of-mysql.html

Answer (score 4):

If you always use both columns (or the first one of the index) in your `WHERE` / `GROUP BY` / `ORDER BY` you should use `index(A,B)`.

The second one in the index (in this case B) cannot be used separately, but the first one can (only the first one in any case).

So if you never use B on its own, then `index(A,B)` should be sufficient. If you never use A on its own, but you do use B, then do `index(B,A)`. If you do use both separately, but mostly together, then add the other index separately.

Comment: Thanks Topener, but what about the query 2. `where A > 3 and A < 10 and B > 12 and B < 20`? Isn't it a case where separate index for B is needed?

Answer (score 2):

An index on `(A,B)` will handle your cases 1, 3 and 4.

For case 2, where you have a range query on `A` and also on `B`, it's best to have an index on `(A)`, and a separate index on `(B)`, and let the database decide which is best for the query.  It can decide on the fly which index is more selective based on the values in the query.  MySQL will only use one index in this case, so it will pick which one it thinks will give it the smallest set of rows for the given range, and then will walk through those rows filtering by the other range.

So to handle all of those cases you mentioned, I recommend indices on:

- `(A,B)`
- `(B)`

The index on `(A,B)` can be used just like an index just on `(A)` whenever the database needs an index on just `(A)`, so defining those two indices is just like having an "all of the above" set of `(A)`, `(B)` and `(A,B)`.

Also note that if you ever want to order by or group by `(B, A)`, you would want an index on `(B,A)` as well as `(A,B)`.  Order is important!